# Lightning Tab With Next And Back Buttons

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components

In my page I'm using `lightning-vertical-navigation`. With Static and Dynamic Values. Each page has two Button `next` and `previous`

On-click of Next it should go to `next` navigation page. Click of `previous` button it goes to previous navigation Page.

**For Example:**

```
 School
 Class
 Student
    Student1
    Student2
    Student3
 Finish
```

Student1
    Student2
    Student3 are the dynamic values.

**Static Navigation Code below**

```
    handleOnNextPage() {     
        if (this.selectedItems === "school") {
          this.selectedItem = "class";
          return;
        }

        if (this.selectedItems === "class") {
          this.selectedItem = "student";
          return;
        }

        if (this.selectedItems === "student") {

        // it should goes to first sudent

          return;
        }
      }
```

We can Navigate from School to Class and Class to Student by using navigation Name Since it is static value.

My Question here is How we can navigate from Student to Student1 and Student1 to Student2 so on. Since it's a dynamic value.

**Note:** We have a option to add the new students in Student tab. Dynamically the value will be displayed under Students as Student{Name}

My thought process is we can add the value in the array and loop. not sure about this approach. can anyone Please help me how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 2):

You've basically already answered this. Just create an array and use that to navigate around.

```
next() {
  this.selectedItems = this.tabs[this.tabs.indexOf(this.selectedItems)+1];
}
prev() {
  this.selectedItems = this.tabs[this.tabs.indexOf(this.selectedItems)-1];
}
```

This answer presumes that `tabs` are the names of the tabs in order:

```
tabs = ['school','class','student','student1','finish'];
```